# Calculate summary data with R

Tags: r, casting, summary

I have data frame that looks like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(factor1 = rep(c("A", "B"),50),
                 factor2 = rep(c("X","X", "Y", "Y"),25),
                 value = rnorm(100))
```

I want to calculate some summary values for factor1:factor2 pairs.  I calculated the means and sd using:

```
summary <- as.matrix(cast(df, factor1~factor2, mean))
summary.sd <- as.matrix(cast(df, factor1~factor2, sd))
summary.table <- t(rbind(summary, summary.sd))
colnames(summary.table) <- c("A.mean", "B.mean", "A.sd", "B.sd")
```

But I would like to add to summary.table the p-value from a t.test comparing A vs B.  So far I have done this, but not only does this not write to summary.table but i can't get the names of the factor2 variable to print out along with it:

```
for (measurement in levels(df$factor2)) print(t.test(value~factor1, data=subset(df, factor2==measurement)))
```

I figure there must be some simple way to do this, or maybe a package that I am not aware of that would make this much more straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

First, get `mean` and `sd` summaries using `ddply` from `plyr` using `summarise`

```
require(plyr)
require(reshape2)
o1 <- ddply(df, .(factor1, factor2), summarise, mean = mean(value), sd=sd(value))

#   factor1 factor2       mean        sd
# 1       A       X 0.03746854 0.8730525
# 2       A       Y 0.18352432 0.7635439
# 3       B       X 0.10317706 1.0494930
# 4       B       Y 0.03745372 0.9876173
```

Then, get `p-values` for `t-test` with NULL `mean(A) = mean(B)` for both `X` and `Y` levels in `factor2`:

```
o2 <- ddply(df, .(factor2), summarise, pval=t.test(value ~ factor1)$p.value)

#   factor2      pval
# 1       X 0.8108754
# 2       Y 0.5614256
```

Then, using `reshape2`'s `melt` and `dcast` cast `o1` to the desired format.

```
o1.mc <- dcast(melt(o1, c("factor1", "factor2")), factor2 ~ variable + factor1)

#   factor2     mean_A     mean_B      sd_A      sd_B
# 1       X 0.03746854 0.10317706 0.8730525 1.0494930
# 2       Y 0.18352432 0.03745372 0.7635439 0.9876173
```

Now, merge it with `o2`:

```
merge(o1.mc, o2)

#   factor2     mean_A     mean_B      sd_A      sd_B      pval
# 1       X 0.03746854 0.10317706 0.8730525 1.0494930 0.8108754
# 2       Y 0.18352432 0.03745372 0.7635439 0.9876173 0.5614256
```